# Vim mapping Cntrl-i to toggle between normal and insert

Tags: vim

```
inoremap <C-i> <Esc> " cntrl-i to switch to normal
nnoremap <C-i> a "cntrl-i to switch to insert
```

Tried the following to have `cntrl-i` toggle between normal and insert modes. However, when I toggle into insert mode it works but pastes everything after `a`, this happens also when replacing `a` with `i`. It fails completely when in insert mode and just inserts a tab.

Alternatively if anybody has better suggestions for a mapping to toggle between both, I'm all ears. I wanted to do caps lock however couldn't find a mapping for it in the vim docs.

Comment: As documented in [`:help map-comments`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#map-comments) there cannot be in-line comments after maps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont put comments after maps:

```
inoremap <C-i> <Esc>
nnoremap <C-i> i
```

Comment: In insert mode, this still doesn't switch to normal, instead it adds a tab.

Comment: This works for me @Ge0rges. Note that `<C-i>` and `<Tab>` are equivalent. Sounds like your mapping is getting unmapped.

Comment: Any clues as to why or how I can find out why?

Comment: @Ge0rges https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7722/how-to-debug-a-mapping